# Understanding Syntactic divergence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset, distribution, stanford-nlp

I am trying to read a paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14444 Section 6.1 of the paper describes Syntactic divergence. I have confusion regarding the distribution graphs and split of the dataset.

- If a paper proposes a new test set for the NLP domain under the
  distribution shift concept, should the Syntactic divergence
  distribution be similar to all proposed test sets?
- If the Syntactic divergence distribution of the proposed test set is
  different, what does it mean?
- If my understanding is correct, Syntactic divergence is a difficulty
  measure metric so if the Syntactic divergence distribution of new
  test sets differs a lot from the original test set, does it means
  that the proposed test set is more difficult? Is it a good
  indication?
- In summary, the distribution of new test sets should be similar, or
  can it be different?

Could someone from the NLP field help me to clear my doubts?

Thank you!